# How to fix jquery hover show description

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#nav li h3").hover(function() {
      $(this)
      .parent("li")
      .find("p")
      .css({
         position:"absolute"
      })
      .removeClass("hidden")
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity: 1}, "fast");
   }, function() {
      $(this)
      .parent()
      .find("p")
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity: 0}, "fast");
});
</script>
```

and html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
   <li>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td><h3>name</h3></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="hidden">description</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

... and css style:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

when i hover name is result not show tooltip of

tag, how to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following errors in your code:

1. A syntax error.  You were missing a closing `})`
2. `.parent("li")` needs to be changed to `.closest("li")` in two places because `.parent()` only looks up one level
3. The `position: absolute` is not needed if you want it to display in place where it is in the HTML
4. You can just use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` instead of `removeClass()` and `.animate()`.
5. When you call `.stop()`, you want to also clear it from the queue with `.stop(true)`.

This code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#nav li h3").hover(function() {
      $(this)
      .closest("li")
      .find("p")
      .stop(true)
      .fadeIn("fast");
   }, function() {
      $(this)
      .closest("li")
      .find("p")
      .stop(true)
      .fadeOut("fast");
   });
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3A4fv/

I realized this can be done much shorter like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#nav li h3").hover(function() {
      $(this)
      .closest("li")
      .find("p")
      .stop(true)
      .fadeToggle("fast");
   });
});
```

Working demo of this one here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QCEy6/

Comment: Added an even shorter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you remove table tr td, code will working

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>
      <h3>name</h3>
      <p class="hidden">description</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```